# Getting rid of llvmpipe. Installing open source drivers correctly

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

My video card is Radeon R9 270 Dual-X. I've read a lot about overwhelming performance of OpenSource drivers compared to proprietary ones, so I'd really like to move to OS drivers. 
However!
I did everything as mentioned on the [official Ubuntu wiki page](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_amd) concerning AMD video drivers but still, when I run

```
glxinfo | grep rend
```

I get

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe
```

Which means (as I suppose) that I still use software renderer, which is definitely not good for gaming.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I fixed this problem by upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04, but this is not a real fix, just some sort of low qualification level workaround.
I think, that the root of the problem lies somewhere in an uncorrectly installed drivers, so a possible solution to this is reinstalling Oibaf drivers. To do so run:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo reboot

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Create an answer with your solution.

Comment: I have no tested solution

Comment: oibaf packages for 14.04 are only for installs that come from an 14.04 or 14.04.1 image. (ie. no lts mesa  packages.

Comment: doug, could you please provide more information on this?